# Rig Veda - can't find the right text -

Tags: rig-veda, chakras

Please take a look at this [book](https://books.google.pl/books?id=KiPwBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=In%20the%20wild%20ecstasy%20of%20divine%20immortality,%20I%20destroyed%20all%20the%20ninety-nine%20cities&source=bl&ots=H8LDIvCQ09&sig=ACfU3U1FDQCjq23RLvOojTOqC0g25n0qVQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvhc3fmO_oAhXNlIsKHdj4DU4Q6AEwAHoECAwQKA#v=onepage&q=In%20the%20wild%20ecstasy%20of%20divine%20immortality%2C%20I%20destroyed%20all%20the%20ninety-nine%20cities&f=false).
It reports many times pieces of the Rig Veda. For example on page 25.

> May the three-seated (tri-vandhura) and mentally-governed (manasa-yukta) come – spreading over the five abodes (Rig Veda VII.69.2)

Or on page 95:

> 'In the wild ecstasy of divine immortality, I destroyed all the
>   ninety-nine cities of Shambara; And utterly the hundredth abode, when
>   helping the servant of the gods in the Atithgva lineage' (Rig Veda.
>   IV.26.3)

I tried to find the original texts in the Rig Veda. But in those verses there is completely different text. And sometimes there is no reference at all.

I am expecially interested in this one:

> According to the Vedas, there are Seven Chakras in each 'layer', of
>   which consists of Three Worlds. But, there are 33 'Layers' of these
>   Chakras, of which correspond to the Thirty Three Gods of the Vedic
>   Philosophy (Rig Veda. II.6.9).

This one does not seem to be a citation. Anyway there is not such as II.6.9 - the last verse is 8.

You can check here: https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/index.htm

Can anyone help to find (Rig Veda. II.6.9) and to explain why on page 95 based on that verse(s) he states that there are ninety-nine chakras?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE! Can you please provide name/link of the book you are referring in the Q?

Comment: ups, sorry. I just added the link to the first sentence

Comment: @Pikk You need to ask a separate question about the problem with the translation. In this post your main question was "Rig Veda - can't find the right text" which is now answered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can anyone explain Rig Veda III.6.9 and how does it relate to chakras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40040/can-anyone-explain-rig-veda-iii-6-9-and-how-does-it-relate-to-chakras)

Comment: you've asked essentially the same question in 2 different question postings. duplicate.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Not a duplicate, see my comment above as to why OP asked a second question. This is an 'identification-request' question about a particular RV verse while the other is about the meaning of the verse.

Comment: Very interesting to also note 1) The Dark series in Netflix 2) The Thirty Third Degree in Free Masonry... Nudge, Nudge, Wink, Wink,,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This one does not seem to be a citation. Anyway there is not such as II.6.9 - the last verse is 8.

in III.6.9 there is mention of 33 Gods. [With these, borne on one ear, Agni, approach us, or borne on many, for thy steeds are able.
Bring, witb their Dames, the Gods, the Three and-Thirty, after thy Godlike nature, and be joyful.](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv03006.htm) May be misprint?

Comment: Thanks, yes, it's probalby a misprint. But how can this be interpreted as 99 chakras?