# Can anyone explain Rig Veda III.6.9 and how does it relate to chakras?

Tags: rig-veda, chakras

[Here](https://books.google.pl/books?id=KiPwBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=In%20the%20wild%20ecstasy%20of%20divine%20immortality,%20I%20destroyed%20all%20the%20ninety-nine%20cities&source=bl&ots=H8LDIvCQ09&sig=ACfU3U1FDQCjq23RLvOojTOqC0g25n0qVQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvhc3fmO_oAhXNlIsKHdj4DU4Q6AEwAHoECAwQKA#v=onepage&q=In%20the%20wild%20ecstasy%20of%20divine%20immortality%2C%20I%20destroyed%20all%20the%20ninety-nine%20cities&f=false) on page 95 the author states that

> According to the Vedas, there are Seven Chakras in each 'layer', of
>   which consists of Three Worlds. But, there are 33 'Layers' of these
>   Chakras, of which correspond to the Thirty Three Gods of the Vedic
>   Philosophy

This is about Rig Veda. III.6.9.

I would like to understand why

> "With these, borne on one ear, Agni, approach us, or borne on many,
>   for thy steeds are able. Bring, witb their Dames, the Gods, the Three
>   and-Thirty, after thy Godlike nature, and be joyful

and other verses explain what the author says, that there are ninety-nine chakras. I see no mentioning about chakras in this part of the book.

How to understand/explain that?

Thank you
.

Comment: I think you can't really compare two different interpretations of Vedas. See [Which are the methodologies for interpreting Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35311/which-are-the-methodologies-for-interpreting-vedas). You have to choose one or the other.

Comment: Yogis like Sri Ganapati muni did research in various aspects of Yoga.  The cryptic language of Rig Veda can be understood by Sages like him. In order to understand the cryptic language of ancient literature, one must be having the intuitive understanding of that language.  It is like asking to explain a research paper in Medical Science. :-)

Comment: An author should be more explicit in their references. Saying 'according to the vedas' is not a reference. It would be best to ask the author where exactly it says this, otherwise it is just hearsay and the author's opinion. The microcosm and macrocosm are built in the same way. You might like to read Arthur Avalon's translation of the 'Mahanirvana Tantra'. He goes into more detail as to scriptural references and the correlation of macrocosmic and microcosmic.